# htaccess on one.com webspace

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Recently I moved my websites to the hoster *one.com*. They have setup an automated mechanism (I dunno what they use to achieve that) to rewrite any first-level folder on the webspace to a subdomain.

I.e. the folder `http://example.com/folder1/` will be also available as `http://folder1.example.com/`

Now, I have a site, that is using quite a lot javascript to include pages from a *hardcoded, static* source. Due to the **SOP** the scripts are working depending on which hardcoded reference they use.

So, to make sure that everybody gets a working version of the website, i wanted to redirect the **direct** folder access to the subdomain as well.

My htaccess for this - which is working localy and on various htaccess-testers out there - seems to be not working with one.com:

```
RewriteEngine On 
#Rewrite Access to folder1-folder to subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1.*?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://folder1.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Since I don't know the exact mechanism one.com is using to achieve the mentioned behaviour it might just be a conflict with my rules.

Support says, that all the used commands are fully supported, and therefore wasn't be able to tell what's going wrong...

Does anybody have encountered something similiar and has a hint for me?

---

just fiured out the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On #does not work
```

vs.

```
RewriteEngine on #does work
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the actual request was made for `/folder/` and not the URI (which can internally be rewritten). Try:

```
#Rewrite Access to folder1-folder to subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /+folder1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ http://folder1.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Valid point - but the actual solution was way simpler. Just a case-issue :-)